# Show that $a_{rs} = kb_{rs}$ given $a_{rs}b_{tu}-a_{ru}b_{st}+a_{st}b_{ru}-a_{tu}b_{rs} =0$

Tags: linear-algebra, tensors

If $a_{rs}$ and $b_{rs}$ are both symmetric systems, such that
$$ a_{rs}b_{tu}-a_{ru}b_{st}+a_{st}b_{ru}-a_{tu}b_{rs} =0 , $$
for any $r, s, t, u$.
Show that there is some constant $k$ such that for any $r, s$, we have $a_{rs} = kb_{rs}$.

One can understand $a_{rs}$ as the entry of a matrix in the $r$-th row and $s$-th column. Symmetric system $a_{rs}$ implies such matrix is symmetric, i.e. $a_{rs} = a_{sr}$.

I am currently self learning tensor analysis from the textbook [Applications of Tensor Analysis, A. J. McConnell](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0486603733) but cannot find a solution to this problem (EXAMPLES I, question 4, p. 17) on my own.

I have tried to rearrange the indices $r, s, t, u$ within the expression, in an attempt to create new equations that can be combine with the given the expression to eliminat/simplify but it was not successful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try dividing by $b_{rs}$ on both sides:
$$b_{tu}\frac{a_{rs}}{b_{rs}}=\frac{a_{ru}b_{st}}{b_{rs}}-\frac{a_{st}b_{ru}}{b_{rs}}+a_{tu}$$
But due to symmetry, the left side, and thus the right side, should remain the same if we switch $r\leftrightarrow s$ and $t\leftrightarrow u$:
$$b_{tu}\frac{a_{rs}}{b_{rs}}=\frac{a_{st}b_{ru}}{b_{rs}}-\frac{a_{ru}b_{st}}{b_{rs}}+a_{tu}$$
Adding these we get
$$2\,b_{tu}\frac{a_{rs}}{b_{rs}}=2\,a_{tu}\implies\frac{a_{rs}}{b_{rs}}=\frac{a_{tu}}{b_{tu}}$$
The left side only depends on $r$ and $s$; the right side only depends on $t$ and $u$. So both must be equal to a constant independent of $r,s,t,u$, and we can call that constant $k$.

Comment: Thank you very much. It is very helpful. I think we can also use the same approach without dividing each side by $b_{rs}$.